# How do I efficiently split the values from a text file into my program?

Tags: c#, arrays, string, char

I have a text file where I have to split the values with every space (' ') and newline('\n'). It does not work very well since every newline has a carriage return connected to it (\r\n).

```
char[] param = new char[] {' ','\n','\r'}; // The issue
string[] input = fill.Split(param);
```

The param array does not accept a '\r\n' parameter as n split argument, that is why I used '\n' and '\r' separately, but it does not work the way it needs to work. Any suggestions?

Comment: How about `Environment.NewLine`?

Comment: Environment.NewLine is string, not char

Comment: @KamilNowak: But you can split with string. Look at my answer.

Comment: of course ;) I've forgot about that one

Comment: Hey user2037244, you've asked 18 questions on StackOverflow and not accepted a single answer for any of them.

Answer (score 0):

Use [the overload of String.Split() that takes an array of strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/tabh47cf.aspx) instead of the overload that takes an array of chars.

Answer (score 0):

There is [an overload that accepts strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf.aspx):

```
string[] input = fill.Split(
    new string[] { " ", Environment.NewLine },
    StringSplitOptions.None);
```

You can also use [`Environment.NewLine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline.aspx) instead of `"\r\n"`.

But if you want to support all kinds of line-endings, you better specify all the popular possiblities:

```
string[] input = fill.Split(
    new string[] { " ", "\n", "\r\n" },
    StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string[] result = text.Split(new string[] { " ", Environment.NewLine },
                            StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string fill = @"one two three four";
string[] result = fill.Split(new string[] { " ", Environment.NewLine },
                            StringSplitOptions.None);

foreach (var s in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```

Here is a [`DEMO`](http://ideone.com/UG6wQX).

But remember, [`Environment.NewLine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline.aspx) is

> A string containing "\r\n" for non-Unix platforms, or a string
>   containing "\n" for Unix platforms.